# Creating the same query in annotate

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a query that will get all of user 3's following list. I also want to check if the logged in user is following each of user 3's following list. So for example let's say user 3's following list is: `2,3,4` and the logged in user is following 2 and 4. So the result would be: `2:1, 3:0 and 4:1` 1 indicating that the logged in user is following and 0 indicating the logged in user is not following. I'm trying to accomplish this using this query:

**Following model**

```
class Following(models.Model):
    target = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='followers', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    follower = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='targets', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} is followed by {}'.format(self.target, self.follower)
```

**Query**

```
User.objects.filter(followers__follower=3).order_by('-followers__created_at').\
    annotate(is_following=Count('followers', filter=Q(followers__follower=self.request.user), distinct=True))
```

However, for some reason the `annotate` query is not running at all. I think it is because it is the same query as the main query, but with different parameters. How can I make it so that my query works in the way I want it to work?

Comment: What do you mean with "not running"? What result do you get? What Django version do you use?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I feel like the query is not working correctly since it outputs 0 all the time in `is_following` when it should be 1 with it being the user follows that user